# How can I create tables with a default schema using Grails 3.0.1 and Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0

I have found references on how to do this using DataSource.groovy however I haven't managed to get it working with Grails 3 application.yml. This doesn't work:

```
grails:
    hibernate:
        cache:
            queries: false
        default_schema: "bread"
```

The tables are created with 'public' schema.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it was a bug that's been corrected now, but the `hibernate` part of your config needs to live on the root, not under `grails`.

```
hibernate:
    default_schema: SCHEMA
```

Comment: this seems like a comment, not an answer. Posting the full code would help

Comment: @U47 How to do this with multiple datasources ?

Comment: @NarayanSubedi Do what? This specifies a default schema for the default datasource. If you have multiple datasources, you need to specify the datasource of your domain objects manually anyway. Just specify the schema as well.